# MyBatis ORA-01745: invalid host/bind variable name

Tags: java, oracle, mybatis, spring-mybatis

I have an insert statement in MyBatis using Oracle 11g R2 on the backend with the Oracle ojdbc6 driver.

I am repeatedly getting

`java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01745: invalid host/bind variable name`

However I don't see what is causing the issue, I'm not using any Oracle reserved Keywords.

```
<insert id="createRecord" parameterType="org.appliication.core.domain.TRRecord"
            statementType="PREPARED" useGeneratedKeys="true" keyColumn="ID" keyProperty="id">

        INSERT INTO T_TR_PUBLICATION p (
          p.TR_UID,
          p.TITLE,
          p.ITEM_TITLE,
          p.COVER_DATE,
          p.HAS_ABSTRACT,
          p.ISSUE,
          p.SORT_DATE,
          p.VOLUME,
          p.BEGIN_PAGE,
          p.END_PAGE,
          p.ACCESSION_NO,
          p.ISSN,
          p.DOI,
          p.FUNDING_TEXT
        )
        VALUES (
          #{trUid, jdbcType=NULL},
          #{title, jdbcType=NULL},
          #{titleItem, jdbcType=NULL},
          #{coverDate, jdbcType=NULL},
          #{hasAbstract, jdbcType=NULL},
          #{issue, jdbcType=NULL},
          #{sortDate, jdbcType=NULL}
          #{journalVolume, jdbcType=NULL},
          #{pageBegin, jdbcType=NULL},
          #{pageEnd, jdbcType=NULL},
          #{accessionNo, jdbcType=NULL},
          #{issn, jdbcType=NULL},
          #{doi, jdbcType=NULL},
          #{fundingText, jdbcType=NULL}
        )

    </insert>
```

Comment: Don't know MyBatis, but try removing the `jdbcType=NULL`, since `NULL` is not a valid JDBC type for the purpose. You cannot bind a value to the `NULL` type.

Comment: is this `org.appliication.core.domain.TRRecord` package/class path correct?

Comment: @Andreas, MyBatis will not work without the jdbcType=NULL because if an object like String is null, it maps to JdbcType.OTHER which Oracle JDBC driver does not understand thus it throws an Exception: UncategorizedSQLException: Error setting null for parameter #8 with JdbcType OTHER . Try setting a different JdbcType for this parameter or a different jdbcTypeForNull configuration property. Cause: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type

Comment: @Mastah, I've confirmed the path is correct, in fact my IDE autocompletes the path

Comment: @greyfox Then specify the actual type you want, e.g. `VARCHAR`. This way, both a value ("abc") and a null will map to a type the JDBC driver can understand. However, I would have thought that MyBatis would have examined the types of the fields in `TRRecord` to automatically choose the correct type.

Comment: @Andreas, you are right, you have to specify the JDBC type for anything that can potentially be NULL

Comment: @greyfox Too bad MyBatis is too dumb to figure out the jdbcType from the (implicit) javaType. I have created an official answer so you can accept it. :-)

Comment: accepted, from the docs it kind of suggest it is actually the Oracle JDBC driver which doesn't map JdbcType.OTHER, but either way an annoyance for sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the actual type you want, e.g. `VARCHAR`. This way, both a value (`"abc"`) and a `null` will map to a type the JDBC driver can understand.