# MyBatis inserting null to a DB2 DATE column

Tags: db2, mybatis

Using MyBatis (Version 3.2.5) I am trying to Update a DB2 DATE column with NULL, but getting this below error

```
org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: Error setting null for parameter #5 with JdbcType NULL . Try setting a different JdbcType for this parameter or a different jdbcTypeForNull configuration property. Cause: com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.SqlException: [ibm][db2][jcc][10281][10295] JDBC type 0 is not yet supported.
; uncategorized SQLException for SQL []; SQL state [null]; error code [-99999]; [ibm][db2][jcc][10281][10295] JDBC type 0 is not yet supported.; nested exception is com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.SqlException: [ibm][db2][jcc][10281][10295] JDBC type 0 is not yet supported.
```

I tried the below suggestions, but they are not working for me

[MyBatis - jdbcTypeForNull Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32081252/mybatis-jdbctypefornull-oracle/32742337#32742337)

Answer (score 1):

The exception is thrown from [line 39 of BaseTypeHandler](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.mybatis/mybatis/3.2.5/org/apache/ibatis/type/BaseTypeHandler.java#BaseTypeHandler).

Set a break point to check the current value of `jdbcType.TYPE_CODE`. It should work fine when it equals java.sql.Types.TIMESTAMP (93), that might not be the case.

So if not the case, 
Expected actual type for `this` being [DateTypeHandler](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.mybatis/mybatis/3.2.5/org/apache/ibatis/type/DateTypeHandler.java).
You might then have to define your own *DateTypeHandler*, just extend it and override method `setParameter` from *BaseTypeHandler*, actually just replace variable `jdbcType.TYPE_CODE` with forced `java.sql.Types.TIMESTAMP`.
To use it by default for all Date parameters, register it in the typeHandler section of mybatis-config.xml (or Spring). Otherwise set the typeHandler attribute for concerned parameter in the insert statement.

Comment: Thank you. I figured whats causing the issue and the solution

Comment: what was it then?

Comment: I posted the solution below.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution..

in mybatis-config.xml, I had

```
<setting name="jdbcTypeForNull" value="NULL" />
```

I changed it like below.

```
<configuration>
    <settings>
        <setting name="jdbcTypeForNull" value="DATE" />             
    </settings>    
</configuration>
```

Comment: I think this might cause problems when you want to pass null to a column of another type. This is global config ... you could try to handle the issue more locally when setting the parameter: `#{yourNullDateParam, jdbcType=DATE}`

Comment: It all depends on the requirement and DB design.
In my case, we want to default to NULL for DATE columns and update/re-set NULL on certain scenarios.